# Camera blocked in windows

Tags: windows-7, camera

I am using two laptops one has **Windows8.1** and other has **Windows 7 enterprise**. Now when I am, trying to use a application which asks you take your picture (for example skype) I get this picture.

I checked camera roll folder on my laptop it has saved this image when I clicked camera icon and captured video when I clicked video icon.

It looks like someone has placed this picture in front of camera.

To fix this, I tried to disable/re-enable the camera, also uninstall/Re-install camera drivers.

[image]

Comment: are you sure there's no physical cover/slide for the camera? Some laptops have that (similar to lens cover in compact cameras) and/or function key to enable/disable camera. Have you looked through laptop's user manual?

Comment: @AcePL lolzz...no..I am seeing green LED light flashes which indicates that camera has started, but instead of showing my face (when camera facing me) it shows this blocked picture.

Comment: OK, what's the make/models of the laptops?

Comment: @AcePL **Lenovo MT ThinkPad ThinkPad Edge E431**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this problem, follow steps below:

1. Press <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>
2. Type in (Run) box **devmgmt.msc**
3. Press "Enter/Return" key
4. Device Management window opened
5. Look for Imaging Device >> Expand it
6. Uninstall the driver, also click the checkbox which says "delete the driver"
7. Once driver is installed completely, right click on root of tree looking structure of devices >> click "Scan for hardware changes"
8. Once done, try your camera if not open , try restarting the system and then try it will work.

This worked for me.